# Deploy the app on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am following [this tutorial](https://console.cloud.google.com/start/appengine) to see how Google App Engine (Java) works. I was able to successfully build the app:

```
cd appengine-try-java-master
mvn clean install
```

The issues happens at the last (deployment) stage on Windows. The tutorial says that it's necessary to run this command (the number `1111` is not the original one due to security reasons):

```
appcfg.cmd -A master-scanner-1111 update target\appengine-try-java-1.0
```

I opened `cmd` and pasted this command. The following message appears:
`appcfg.cmd  is not recognized...`
Then I executed just `update target\appengine-try-java-1.0`, however this did not deploy the app.

Comment: Use a full path to appcfg.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the previous steps they give you instructions to download the Google App Engine SDK, but this is just a package of directories and not an installer (much like how java is packaged).  The appcfg.cmd exists within that set of directories, so the user will need to add the "bin" folder in that package to their path (or, as suggested, use the full path in the command).  The Google documentation is not specific enough for a person just starting out IMHO.  I had the same problem.